# Sails.js get href for route with params

Tags: node.js, routes, sails.js

I'm makeing small Sails.js application. I have a very simple route like:

'/foo': 'FooController.index',
'/foo/:category': 'FooController.category',

My question is: how to make an url in server side rendered view to a category as a param.

I have something like:

```
<%= sails.getUrlFor('FooController.index') %>
```

for index, but I'd like to have something like

```
<%= sails.getUrlFor('FooController.index', {'category':'bar') %>
```

for a category.

Is there any function to do this like above? I don't want to hardcode the urls.

Thanks in advance and let the power be with you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the options you need as a query string on the URL returned from `getUrlFor()`:

```
<%= sails.getUrlFor('FooController.index') %>?category=bar
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such helper function in sailsjs *(or expressis)*. You can use **.replace()** function in addition to the **sails.getUrlFor()** function to generate the url:

```
<%= sails.getUrlFor('FooController.index').replace(':category', 'bar') %>
```

As a more general solution take a look at [named routes](https://github.com/alubbe/named-routes) package